# antlr4 / swift : how to differentiate between a function call expression and c style value casting

Tags: c, swift, parsing, antlr4

I am trying to parse a swift unit which has this c-style casting in it:

let dist = (Double) (earthRadius * c);

According to swift reference we have here:

*postfix_expression :
  postfix_expression function_call_argument_clause # function_call_expression*

i added:

*| '(' type ')' postfix_expression             # c_style_cast*

But antlr4 goes into the function call expression every time.

How can force antlr to go into the c style cast?

Thanks,

Roy

Comment: If you have `(f)(1)`, and `f` is a function, it's a function call (the parentheses are allowed).  It could also be an expression that evaluates to a function (or function pointer). On the other hand, If `f` is a data type (optionally followed by an abstract declarator), it's a type cast.  The only difference is what `f` is.  So in your example, it would need to look up `Double`, and its type would affect how the expression is parsed.

Comment: I understand swift allows f(1) to be written (f)(1), very weird. But why can't the parser understand it is not a function call? I mean are u saying there is not way for antlr to understand that?

Comment: All I can say is that in C, the syntax alone is not always enough to make the distinction.  In some cases, it is necessary to see how `f` was declared.  So it needs to do a symbol table lookup before it can correctly parse the expression.

Comment: First, thank u for your help. I am still trying to understand what u mean. Are u saying there is nothing to do at the parse stage? That i will have to analyze the function expressions and decide which one are real and which are this c-style casting? Thanks.

Comment: I'm just saying that you'll have to know what the user-defined symbols are in order to parse the expression.  Knowing that `f` is an identifier is not always sufficient.  You sometimes need to know what kind of identifier it is in order to know which grammar rule is correct.